# Combining Clustering and classification in Python

Tags: python, classification

There is a clustering method in Python called K-means. After Clustering Process, I want to calculate accuracy of each cluster based on SVM or another classification method.

How can I do this?

Comment: This isn't a proper question for StackOverflow. You need to ask how to solve a specific problem with your code, and provide an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You cannot ask others to write code for you.

Comment: Ok - I edit My question and Write it Another way

Comment: something Like this https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24324/how-to-use-k-means-outputs-extracted-features-as-svm-inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any clustering, in the end of the day, it tries to maximize the distance between different clusters, while minimizing the distance within clusters.  And the distance itself is a measure you have to define, i.e., Manhatten, Euclidean, Statistical, etc.  There is no true "accuracy" of clustering because it depends on what your data looks like, and the amount of clusters you decide. In fact, many times if you re-run the same algorithm after shuffling the data, you will obtain different clusters!

Take this example:  You try to cluster animals/insects into 3 types.  And the animals are a bear, snake, spider and raccoon.

Because the defined amount of clusters is 3, the clusters would probably be:

1) Bear, raccoon
2) Snake
3) Spider

It doesn't necessarily mean that bears and raccoons are very similar, its just that they're closer to each other compared to other animals.

With the above being said, the best way to analyze the "accuracy" of each cluster would be to use the Silhouette Analysis.  This analysis measures the distance of each point to other points within the cluster, and compares it with the distance of each point to other points that are outside the cluster.

If one point is identified to have a smaller distance to another point outside the current cluster, that means that the data point is labelled poorly.

Please see this link, it will give you a step-by-step guide for using K-means to create your clusters, then evaluating your clustering "accuracy" using the Silhouette analysis!

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html